# isinstance behavior with module reload

Tags: python, import, reload, isinstance

Given the following two .py files:

aclass.py

```
class A(object):
    pass
```

main.py

```
def importer(klass):
    """
    Used to import classes from there python qalname
    """
    import_ = lambda m, k: getattr(__import__(m, fromlist=k), k)
    klass = klass.split('.')
    module = '.'.join(klass[:-1])
    klass = klass[-1]
    return import_(module, klass)

from aclass import A

import_A = importer('aclass.A')
print isinstance(A(), import_A)  # Expected to be true 
print isinstance(import_A(), A)  # Expected to be true
```

At this stage, everything works fine (my program prints `True\nTrue`)
But if I modify the `importer` method to enforce a reload, ie:

this line:

```
    import_ = lambda m, k: getattr(__import__(m, fromlist=k), k)
```

is replaced by:

```
    import_ = lambda m, k: getattr(reload(__import__(m, fromlist=k)), k)
```

my programs returns

```
False
False
```

And I do not understand this behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reloading a module means re-executing its content, in this case `class A(object): pass`.  So it creates another different class.  It's the same behavior as:

```
class A(object):
    pass
a = A()
class A(object):          # a different class
    pass
print isinstance(a, A)    # False
```

This should be enough to explain why a bare `reload()` is usually a bad idea.  I'm sure others could point to frameworks that implement more sophisticated reloading procedures, e.g. patching the old class to be considered equal to the new one.

Comment: `others could point to frameworks`, I would love that others points me such implementations!

Comment: For more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module